# Event Listener to capture inner html of dynamic class element

Tags: javascript, html

We have a scenario to capture inner html of the html tag whose class name is changing dynamically
For Example

Before Error Message:

```
<spam class="abc"></spam>
```

After Error Message:

```
<spam class="abc_error">Please enter your name</spam>
```

I have Use this code:

```
function addInputEventListener() {
  // Get all input elements on current screen
  const inputElements = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="abc"]');

  // Attach event listener to each element
  for (let i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++) {
    inputElements[i].addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', () => {
       // capture
    });
  }
}
```

The problem is if class name is static then event is getting triggered but after class name changes dynamically, we are not getting any event.